# Side by side (inline) divs with dynamical width (CSS, no JavaScript)

Tags: html, css

Before marking [duplicated] make sure to understand the question.

I'm having trouble to find out the best way to have 2 divs side by side where the first one is dynamic to it's content which can be added and removed. Checking the actual code explains it way more than me. It's basically an editor where there's the lines counter and the code/text part.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a63hu6d/) and code snippet:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#editor {
  cursor: default;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

#lines {
  background-color: #2e3436;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 7px;
}

#text {
  background-color: #141414;
  color: #B5834A;
  cursor: text;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: calc(100% - 34px);
}
```

```html
<div id="editor">
  <div id="lines">
    <span>1</span>
    <br><span>2</span>
    <br><span>10</span>
    <br><span>etc</span>
  </div><div id="text">
    <span>&lt;html><br>// Code<br>&lt;/html></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now I'm using `width: calc(100% - 34px);` which does not fix the problem of when I add/remove line numbers that make its div change width.

I have tried multiple values in the CSS property `display`. I suspect something related with tables would work but I would prefer a not workaround and no JavaScript if possible.

If you haven't understood the issue, just remove the `10` and the `etc` and you will notice a white space in the end of the editor/text div.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexboxes:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#editor {
  cursor: default;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex; /* add */
}

#lines {
  background-color: #2e3436;
  color: #fff;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 7px;
}

#lines span {
  display: block; /*add and remove <br>s*/
}

#text {
  background-color: #141414;
  color: #B5834A;
  cursor: text;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  height: 100%;
  /*vertical-align: top;*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor">
  <div id="lines">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>10</span>
    <span>etc</span>
  </div><div id="text">
    <span>&lt;html><br>// Code<br>&lt;/html></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your answer is the best one. I like that it doesn't change much and that it removes the need for the elements `<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

`float` instead of `inline-block`

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#editor {
  cursor: default;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

#lines {
  background-color: #2e3436;
  color: #fff;
  /*display: inline-block;  nooooo */
  float:left; /* yeeeeees */
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 7px;
  text-align: right;  /* missing this :) */
}

#lines span{ display: block;} /* yeeeeyyy */

#text {
  background-color: #141414;
  color: #B5834A;
  cursor: text;
  /*display: inline-block; noooooo */
  /* width: calc(100% - 34px); noooooo */
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor">

  <div id="lines">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>10</span>
    <span>etccccc</span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="text">
    <span>&lt;html><br>// Code<br>&lt;/html></span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @J.Vie you're doing it the wrong way anyways :) - If I have a long line of code - and suddenly it wraps into two lines yore not handling that case. Think about it - I'll show you soon how I'd do it. if that matters at all...

Comment: I admit I'm not that good. I'm doing my best to make an editor that looks like Notepad++ (Twilight theme) just for fun.

Answer (score 1):

ive did myself using float for lines (to not use br's)

```
<div id="editor">
    <div id="lines">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>10</span>
        <span>etc</span>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        <span>&lt;html></span>
        <span>// Code</span>
        <span>&lt;/html></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and display table properties to fit with all screen and get better alignments.

heres the example, works fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/wkd0ssw3/

this will work in any navigator, be careful to use another properties like `display:flex` or `calc`, because may not work in all navigators...

Comment: if u dont want use table stuff, i tried removing all display methods, just placing it flotating with absolute position: https://jsfiddle.net/wkd0ssw3/1/

Answer (score 1):

Put the `.editor` element *inside* the `.text` element, make it a floated block and give the `.text`element 100% width:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#editor {
  cursor: default;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

#lines {
  background-color: #2e3436;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 7px;
}

#text {
  background-color: #141414;
  color: #B5834A;
  cursor: text;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor">
 
  <div id="text">
   <div id="lines">
    <span>1</span>
    <br><span>2</span>
    <br><span>10000</span>
    <br><span>etc</span>
  </div>
    <span>&lt;html><br>// Code<br>&lt;/html></span>
  </div>
</div>
```